# C# try/finally for state cleanup

Tags: c#

Is there any reason (for instance: performance) against moving state "cleanup" code in a finally state?
Example:

```
this.state.InProgress = true;
// logic here
this.state.InProgress = false;
```

With finally state:

```
try
{
    this.state.InProgress = true;
    // logic here
}
finally
{
    this.state.InProgress = false;
}
```

Comment: This may explain things http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106891/overhead-of-try-finally-in-c

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of *bad* reasons for not doing it.  I can't think of any good ones, though.

Comment: Apparently performance is not one of the bad reasons. Can someone find at least 1 valid bad reason?

Comment: by "bad" I meant "invalid"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

And even if the performance would be different (which it is not, see the link in the comment given by Sami), what do you think is more important, speed or correctness? A program which does not work correctly is pretty useless, how fast it may ever be.

The only reason I can think of is that you are 100% sure the "logic" part does not throw any exceptions (now and in the future). That makes the try/finally unneccesary "noise", which decreases readability a bit. Be aware that [it's difficult to make predictions, especially about the future](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/10/20/no-predict/).

Comment: "Be aware that it's difficult to make predictions, especially about the future." I find this funny, coming from you.

Comment: @DrewJordan: LOL, but just because of the Avatar I picked, my skills in making predictions are not better than everyone else's ;-)